# WPF - Listview Databound Column Width Problem

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, wpf-controls

Given below xaml using .Net3.5 -

```
<ListView Name="RawData" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          sorter:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"
          sorter:GridViewSort.ShowSortGlyph="False" >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GetDate}"
                            Width="Auto" sorter:GridViewSort.PropertyName="GetDateTime"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=GetTime}"
                            Width="Auto" sorter:GridViewSort.PropertyName="GetDateTime"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Scan Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScanTimeSec}"
                            sorter:GridViewSort.PropertyName="ScanTimeSecond"  Width="Auto"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Ping Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PingTimeSec}"
                            sorter:GridViewSort.PropertyName="PingTimeSec"  Width="Auto" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Fault Messages"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ErrorMessages}"
                            sorter:GridViewSort.PropertyName="ErrorMessages" Width="Auto"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My problem is with the first and last columns.  They are not automatically resizing to fit the contents of the data.  I could use a fixed width, but that will cause problems later in the project when I let users adjust font size.

Every solution I've found seems to be to set the width="auto" and WPF will do this for you.  However, it doesn't do it.  So as a bit of a newbie at WPF, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: If I remove your custom attached properties, and create some sample data to represent your bindings, it appears to work.  Is there more information that you can provide or perhaps a screen shot of how it is appearing?

Comment: I upload screen shot to http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/DGoteLkN6xFFmlU8z4wymA?feat=directlink.  

From the screen shot, you can see that this listview is one of 4 tabitems in a tabcontrol.   The entire application is built on Prism with 4 separate display regions.  The tabcontrol is dynamically created and positioned by the Unity Framework in Prism. 

I need the custom properties so that my column sort routines work.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the auto property for Width.You can manually set the width.Like Width="100".
I fetched just like this problem and solve by manually enter the width.